# Weights formula for Weighted Linear Regression

Tags: r, regression, weighted-regression

I am working with Weighted Linear Regression.

I have read that I need to calculate the weights $W_i$ to perform this regression.

My question is; **Which formula should be used for calculating the wights?**

One of the recent [Description](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/500818_32a0abc125d94211abe632823be0f4e7.html) used the following formula that is not clear for me.

```
weights <- 1 / lm(abs(lm$residuals) ~ lm$fitted.values)$fitted.values^2
```

Could you please provide me with a source that may help me.

Comment: One source for that formula is your link, beginning with the sentence "If the variances of the observations or their functional form are somehow known, you can use that."

Comment: The code implements the mathematical formula he used: it computes the reciprocal squares of the fitted values.

Comment: I'm not quoting your source: I'm quoting the line of code in your question, under the presumption that you understand `R`.  Are you asking how to understand that `R` code?

Comment: The formula implemented by that `R` code is $w_i=1/y_i^2$ where $y_i$ is the fitted value for observation $i$ and $w_i$ is the weight.  The reason why is explained in the post you linked to beginning with the line I originally quoted.

Comment: @whuber, now after you reply, it is clear for me the formula that he used, but in Wikipedia page, weight formula is $W_i=  1/(\sigma_i^2 )$ So why it is different from what he used?

Comment: As he explains at the point I have indicated, you need to make a (very specific) assumption about how $\sigma_i^2$ is related to $y_i^2:$ that's what connects the two approaches.